# Append first line of paragraph to multiple lines

Tags: bash, sed, awk

I have a tab delimited file that contains date, header row, some values, empty row, and then it repeats all over again multiple times. The file looks something like this:

```
November 3, 2011
column_name1    column_name2    column_name3    column_name4
value   value   value   value
value   value   value   value
value   value   value   value
value   value   value   value

November 4, 2011
column_name1    column_name2    column_name3    column_name4
value   value   value   value
value   value   value   value
value   value   value   value
value   value   value   value
```

I am trying to find the right sed or awk commands to tranform the data so it could be used to create charts. I want the transformed data to look like this:

```
date    column_name1    column_name2    column_name3    column_name4
November 3, 2011    value   value   value   value
November 3, 2011    value   value   value   value
November 3, 2011    value   value   value   value
November 3, 2011    value   value   value   value

date    column_name1    column_name2    column_name3    column_name4
November 4, 2011    value   value   value   value
November 4, 2011    value   value   value   value
November 4, 2011    value   value   value   value
November 4, 2011    value   value   value   value
```

Comment: Paste an example file. It isn't clear if you need the word COLUMN exactly or if the columns will actually have different names.

Comment: I have revised my question to show that column names will not have the word COLUMN, but will be actual column names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Awk.

```
BEGIN {
    FS = "\n"
    RS = "\n\n"
    OFS = "\t"
    #ORS = "\n"
}
{
    print "date" OFS $2
    for (i = 3; i <= NF; i++)
        print $1 OFS $i
    print ""
}
```

Comment: I think I'm getting your idea here, but this does not seem to work for me.

Comment: I found one issue so far, I had an extra blank line at the top. After deleting the blank line, I end up getting the same initial date to be printed on all lines.

Comment: Ok, it works! After investigating, I found that the paragraphs were separated by line feed, space, line feed: `"\n \n"`.

Comment: Forgot to mention, I had to make a slight change to the above to make it work properly. `i = 2` needs to be changed to `i = 3`.

Answer (score 3):

Using 'Sed'

Content of 'infile':

```
$ cat infile
November 3, 2011
column_name1    column_name2    column_name3    column_name4
value   value   value   value
value   value   value   value
value   value   value   value
value   value   value   value

November 4, 2011
column_name1    column_name2    column_name3    column_name4
value   value   value   value
value   value   value   value
value   value   value   value
value   value   value   value
```

Content of the sed script:

```
$ cat script.sed
## When line has a date.
/[0-9]\+,[ ]*[0-9]\{4\}/ {
        ## Save date to HS (hold space).
        h
        ## Read next line (header).
        N
        ## Insert 'date' string at the beginning of the line.
        s/.*\n/date\t/
        ## Print and read next line.
        P
        n
}

## Process next line if blank line found.
/^[ \t]*$/ {
        p
        d
}

## Process data inserting the date in the beginning.
## Put at the end of PS (pattern space) the date saved before and exchange it 
## with the rest of the line. Print after that.
G
s/^\(.*\)\n\(.*\)$/\2\t\1/
p
```

Execute the script:

```
$ sed -n -f script.sed infile
date    column_name1    column_name2    column_name3    column_name4
November 3, 2011        value   value   value   value
November 3, 2011        value   value   value   value
November 3, 2011        value   value   value   value
November 3, 2011        value   value   value   value

date    column_name1    column_name2    column_name3    column_name4
November 4, 2011        value   value   value   value
November 4, 2011        value   value   value   value
November 4, 2011        value   value   value   value
November 4, 2011        value   value   value   value
```

Answer (score 2):

This GNU sed solution might work:

```
 sed -r '/^[A-Z][a-z]+\s+[0-9][0-9]?,\s+([0-9]{4})/,/^$/{//{h;/^$/!{s/.*//;N;s/\n/date /;b}}};G;s/(.*)\n(.*)/\2 \1/;' input_file
```

EDIT: I should have included an explanation!

The sed command only changes lines between those that start with a date `/^[A-Z][a-z]+\s+[0-9][0-9]?,\s+([0-9]{4})/`and an empty line `/^$/`.If so, and the line matches one of those two conditions `//` it stores it in the hold space `h`, additonally if the line is not an empty one (i.e. that is a date), it clears it `s/.*//`, appends the next line `N` and then prepends the literal `date` to it `s/\n/data`. When this is all done, it breaks `b` to read in the next line. For all lines following (remember this is within the starting condition), it appends the hold space `G` (line containing the date) to the current line, then using substitution prepends the date and loses the newline `s/(.*)\n(.*)/\2 \1/`(a side effect of the `G` command). Voila!

Comment: Wow, that looks complicated. I'm getting the same date on each line again. I suspect that I will need to verify that I do have "\n\n" between paragraphs.

Comment: Thanks, your solution also works, but I'm accepting the other answer as it was submitted first and it is easier to understand the logic.